# Android app java.lang.IllegalStateException error

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, android-edittext, android-debug

Hi i'm trying to develop a calculator app, which can calculator your lean body mass from given weight and height! everything works fine buy if I left editText empty and press Calculate button then my app is crashed!

here is my code

```
package com.example.bodybuildingcalc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LeanBodyMass extends Activity {
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton male, female;
TextView tv;
int weight_, height_;
static double result;
EditText weight, height;
private static final int MALE = 100;
private static final int FEMALE = 101;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lean_body_mass);
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender_lbm);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_lbm);
    weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight_lbm);
    height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height_lbm);
    male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.male_lbm);
    male.setId(MALE);
    female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.female_lbm);
    female.setId(FEMALE);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (result != 0) {
            tv.setVisibility(0);
            if (result < 0) {
                tv.setText("Your Lean Body Mass is Lesser than Zero!");

            } else {
                tv.setText("Your Lean Body Mass is " + (int) result + "kg");

            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putDouble("RESULT", result);
}

public void Calculate(View v) {

    switch (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case 100:

        if (weight.getText().toString() != ""
                & height.getText().toString() != ""){

            weight_ = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
            height_ = Integer.parseInt(height.getText().toString());
            result = (0.32810 * weight_) + (0.33929 * height_) - 29.5336;
            if (result < 0) {
                tv.setText("Your Lean Body Mass is Lesser than Zero!");
                tv.setVisibility(0);
            } else {
                tv.setText("Your Lean Body Mass is " + (int) result + "kg");
                tv.setVisibility(0);
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Oops! you forgot to enter height and weight",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;

    case 101:
        weight_ = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
        height_ = Integer.parseInt(height.getText().toString());
        result = (0.29569 * weight_) + (0.41813 * height_) - 43.2933;
        if (result < 0) {
            tv.setText("Your Lean Body Mass is Lesser than Zero!");
            tv.setVisibility(0);
        } else {
            tv.setText("Your Lean Body Mass is " + (int) result + "kg");
            tv.setVisibility(0);
        }
        break;
    case -1:
        // first
        if (weight.getText().toString().matches("")) {
            // secound
            if (height.getText().toString().matches("")) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Oops! you forgot to enter height and weight",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // secound-end
            } else {
                // three

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Oops! you forgot to enter weight",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // secound-end
            }

        } else {
            if (height.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Oops! you forgot to enter height!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please Select Your Gender!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

}}
```

here is the Logcat:

```
04-18 00:27:53.206: D/AndroidRuntime(990): Shutting down VM
04-18 00:27:53.216: W/dalvikvm(990): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception       (group=0x4001d800)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not  execute method of the activity
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at com.example.bodybuildingcalc.LeanBodyMass.Calculate(LeanBodyMass.java:64)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at com.example.bodybuildingcalc.LeanBodyMass.Calculate(LeanBodyMass.java:64)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  ... 11 more
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:412)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
04-18 00:27:53.256: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  ... 15 more
```

and here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Weight :"

      />
    <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/weight_lbm"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Height :"

      />
    <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/height_lbm"/>
</LinearLayout>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/gender_lbm"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

  <RadioButton 
      android:text="Male"
      android:id="@+id/male_lbm"
      />
  <RadioButton 
      android:text="Female"
      android:id="@+id/female_lbm"
      />  
   <Button 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Calculate"
       android:onClick="Calculate"
       />   
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result_lbm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer

Comment: You are trying to make an integer out of an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer` indicates that the the number which you are trying to convert into integer is not number or does not exists.

In your case if your `EditText` is **null**  then you can no convert null value into integer.

So make sure you always check for the null value of your `EditText` as below:

```
 public void Calculate(View v) {

   switch (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
   case 100:

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(weight.getText().toString())
            &   !TextUtils.isEmpty(height.getText().toString())){

        weight_ = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
        height_ = Integer.parseInt(height.getText().toString());
        result = (0.32810 * weight_) + (0.33929 * height_) - 29.5336;
        if (result < 0) {
            tv.setText("Your Lean Body Mass is Lesser than Zero!");
            tv.setVisibility(0);
        } else {
            tv.setText("Your Lean Body Mass is " + (int) result + "kg");
            tv.setVisibility(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use TextUtils.isEmpty(edittext.getText().toString()) to validate the edittext. if the edittext is empty, show alert toast to the user.

Answer (score 0):

When your edittext is empty, at runtime Integer.parseInt("");
parseInt method not able to parse any other Strings.
Few example which you can parse using parseInt method is "8", "0", "100", etc.
"8s", "askls", etc These kind of strings not parsable using parseInt method